# Highlight specific UITextView text base on UITextField search (swift2)

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift2, uitextfield, uitextview

I have a UITextField and UIButton to perform search:

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchcodetxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var searchcodebtn: UIButton!
```

On pressing the UIButton, a function is called to search the word given in UITextFiled in UITextView:

```
@IBAction func searchcode(sender: UIButton) {
    //searchcodebtn.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    searchCode()
}
func searchCode(){
    let keyword = self.searchcodetxt.text
    let lowercasekeyword = keyword!.lowercaseString
    let baseString = webcode.text
    let baselowercase = baseString!.lowercaseString
    let attributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: baseString)
    var error: NSError?
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: lowercasekeyword, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)
        let matches = regex.matchesInString(baselowercase, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, baselowercase.characters.count))
        if let match = matches.first {
            let range = match.rangeAtIndex(1)
            if let swiftRange = rangeFromNSRange(range, forString: baselowercase) {
                attributed.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellowColor(), range: match.range)
            }
        }
        webcode.attributedText = attributed
    } catch {
        // regex was bad!
        let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        alertView.title = "Keywords error!"
        alertView.message = "Please use another keywords"
        alertView.delegate = self
        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alertView.show()
        // Delay the dismissal by 5 seconds
        let delay = 5.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            alertView.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(-1, animated: true)
        })
    }
}
func rangeFromNSRange(nsRange: NSRange, forString str: String) -> Range<String.Index>? {
    let fromUTF16 = str.utf16.startIndex.advancedBy(nsRange.location, limit: str.utf16.endIndex)
    let toUTF16 = fromUTF16.advancedBy(nsRange.length, limit: str.utf16.endIndex)
    if let from = String.Index(fromUTF16, within: str),
        let to = String.Index(toUTF16, within: str) {
            return from ..< to
    }
    return nil
}
```

But when I tap on search button it is not coloring the specific word. How to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some changes required in your code to get this to work.

In the `searchCode()` function, `let range = match.rangeAtIndex(1)` will give an app crash for index out of bound.

You can simply use the match.range to add an attribute:

```
if let match = matches.first {

        attributed.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellowColor(), range: match.range)
}
```

Just correcting this line will make your code work, **but** this will highlight only the first match in the text view.

To **highlight all the matches**, you can change this block

```
if let match = matches.first {
        let range = match.rangeAtIndex(1)
        if let swiftRange = rangeFromNSRange(range, forString: baselowercase) {
            attributed.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellowColor(), range: match.range)
        }
    }
```

and add a loop on matches array, to iterate through all matches and add an attribute for highlighting them.

```
for match in matches {
    attributed.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellowColor(), range: match.range)
}
```

So the **complete code** for `searchCode()` will be:

```
func searchCode(){
    let keyword = self.searchcodetxt.text
    let lowercasekeyword = keyword!.lowercaseString
    let baseString = webcode.text
    let baselowercase = baseString!.lowercaseString
    let attributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: baseString)

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: lowercasekeyword, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)
        let matches = regex.matchesInString(baselowercase, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, baselowercase.characters.count))

        for match in matches {
            attributed.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellowColor(), range: match.range)
        }

        webcode.attributedText = attributed
    } catch {
        // regex was bad!
        let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        alertView.title = "Keywords error!"
        alertView.message = "Please use another keywords"
        alertView.delegate = self
        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alertView.show()
        // Delay the dismissal by 5 seconds
        let delay = 5.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            alertView.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(-1, animated: true)
        })
    }
}
```

Now, you would not require the `rangeFromNSRange()` method.

Comment: Did this help you or do you have any other query ?

Comment: This answer is correct. Green for you. Thank you, friend.